# Runtime error in C code (strange double conversion)

Tags: c

I have a strange runtime error in my C code.  The `Integers` comparison here works fine.  But in the `Decimals` comparison, I always get that the second number is larger than the first number, which is false.  I am pretty new to C and programming in general, so this is a complex application to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int choose;
long long neLimit = -1000000000;
long long limit = 1000000000;
bool big(a,b) {
    if ((a >= limit) || (b >= limit))
        return true;
    else if ((a <= neLimit) || (b <= neLimit))
        return true;
    return false;
}
void largerr(a,b) {
    if (a > b)
        printf("\nThe First Number is larger ..\n");
    else if (a < b)
        printf("\nThe Second Number is larger ..\n");
    else
        printf("\nThe Two Numbers are Equal .. \n");
}
int main() {
    system("color e && title Numbers Comparison && echo off && cls");
start:{
    printf("Choose a Type of Comparison :\n\t1. Integers\n\t2. Decimals \n\t\t     I Choose Number : ");
    scanf("%i", &choose);
    switch(choose) {
        case 1:
            goto Integers;
            break;
        case 2:
            goto Decimals;
            break;
        default:
            system("echo Please Choose a Valid Option && pause>nul && cls");
            goto start;
        }
    }
Integers: {
    system("title Integers Comparison && cls");
    long x , y;
    printf("\nFirst Number : \t");
    scanf("%li", &x);
    printf("\nSecond Number : ");
    scanf("%li", &y);
    if (big(x,y)) {
        printf("\nOut of Limit .. Too Big Numbers ..\n");
        system("pause>nul && cls") ; goto Integers;
    }
    largerr(x,y);
    printf("\nFirst Number : %li\nSecond Number : %li\n",x,y);
    goto exif;
}
Decimals: {
    system("title Decimals Comparison && cls");
    double x , y;
    printf("\nFirst Number : \t");
    scanf("%le", &x);
    printf("\nSecond Number : ");
    scanf("%le", &y);
    if (big(x,y)) {
        printf("\nOut of Limit .. Too Big Numbers ..\n");
        system("pause>nul && cls") ; goto Decimals;
    }
    largerr(x,y);
    goto exif;
}
exif:{
    system("pause>nul");
    system("cls");
    main();
}
}
```

Comment: please forget that `goto` exists... that is more important that whatever is breaking your program.

Comment: As a tip, create functions for `Integers` and `Decimals`, and call them instead of using `goto` here.

Comment: As soon as I saw `goto` I stopped trying to find the problem.

Comment: this is a quite pretty use of `goto`. Anyway, please realize that the code you have can easily be transformed into functions, eliminating `goto`s and making it more maintainable.

Comment: largerr function has no types on its parameters.  So it will (probably) default to ``int``, when you feed in a ``double`` wrong things will happen

Comment: Run your program in a debugger.

Comment: When you don't specify a type for function parameters, they default to `int` (if the compiler is so generously set to let you compile). So, your `double` parameters get cast to `int`s. This may be the cause of your problem. You should use two separate versions for your function. One taking 2 `int`s, and one taking 2 `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

**Functions need parameter type declarations.**

When OP calls `big()` and `largerr()` the variables `x y` are `double`.

```
Decimals: {
  ...
  double x , y;
  ... 
  big(x,y)
  ...
  largerr(x,y)
```

These 2 functions are declared

```
bool big(a,b) {
...
void largerr(a,b) {
```

In both functions, the parameters `a b` lack any type information.  Using old school C standards, the function assumes `a b` are `int`.

The result is that 2 `double` are passed and these typically 2*8 bytes are received at the function and expected to be typically 2*4 bytes of `int`.  Thus the type and size of data passed are mis-matched and all sorts of undefined behavior (UB) ensues.

Prototyping would help, as below.

```
bool big(double a, double b)
```

---

On the +side, OP's post was complete.

---

Other concerns:
  `goto`
  call of `main()`
  No return from `main()`
  Should use `lager_double(double, double)` and `lager_long(long, long)`
  Excessive use of labels.